# $V = U_1 \oplus W = U_2 \oplus W = \dots = U_k \oplus W$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and let $U_1, U_2, \dots, U_k$ be subspaces of $V$ such that $\dim U_1 = \dim U_2 = \dots = \dim U_k$. Gotta show that there exists a subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $$V = U_1 \oplus W = U_2 \oplus W = \dots = U_k \oplus W.$$

I let $\dim V = n$ and let $\dim U_i = m$. I then tried taking the basis of all subspaces and extended to a basis of $V$ $$u_{11},u_{21},\dots,u_{m1},u_{12},u_{22},\dots,u_{m2}, \dots, u_{1k},u_{2k},\dots,u_{mk}, x_{mk + 1}, x_{mk + 2}, \dots, x_n.$$ I then let $W = span\{u_{11} +u_{12},u_{12} + u_{13}, \dots, u_{1 (k-1)} + u_{1k}, \dots, u_{m1} + u_{m2},u_{m2} + u_{m3}, \dots, u_{m (k-1)} + u_{mk}, x_{mk + 1}, x_{mk + 2}, \dots, x_n\}$

But this would be a hassle to show it is linearly independent when doing a direct sum with any of the $U_i$'s and when showing it spans $V$.

Is my method right at all? Is there an easier way? Please, any kind of aid or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show if $V=U+W$ and $dimV=dimW+dimU$ then V is the direct sum of U and W?

Comment: If dim$U_i=m$, then dim$V=m-n$. Try to prove that there exists an subspace $V$ with that dimensions that is orthogonal to all $U_i$. If you can do that, that is your direct sum.

Comment: The claim is true only for vector spaces over infinite fields.

Comment: Got it, changed the question

Comment: @user439126 Fair enough, but the point is that if you are trying to prove a statement with a procedure that should work when the statement is false, then perhaps you should second guess that too.

Comment: Oh! Interesting. What about this this result restricts it to only vector spaces over infinite fields?

Comment: @Gae. S. If you could answer this or toss me a hint as to why, would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Gae. S. In that solution, they pop out with $E$ out of no where, which I'm guessing is the union of the all the $U_i$'s, and $d$ and $r$, I have no idea if that's a typo. I am having the hardest time with this proof.

Comment: $E=X{}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: Thanks, and what is $r$? That also pops out out of no where. Is it $d$?